# Stripping Carriage Returns in ADF Data Wrangle not working

Tags: pipeline, azure-data-factory, carriage-return, data-wrangling

I'm currently trying to build an ADF pipeline using the new Data Wrangling Data Flow, which is effectively the Power Query element of PowerBI as far as I can see (I'm more of a PBI developer!).

In the data flow, I am picking up a CSV file from an SFTP location and using the wrangle to transform the data and load into a SQL server database.

I am successfully picking up the file and loading it into a table, however the CSV contains carriage returns within the cells, which cause additional lines to be inserted into my table.

Using the wrangling data flow, I have added a step that removes the carriage return. I can visibly see the change has been applied in the post steps:

Pre Change: [Example of pre change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HublJ.png)

Post Change: [Example of post change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/10BLG.png)

However, when I pass the data wrangling step into my pipeline, it seems to load the data ignoring the step to remove the #(CR)#(LF) - i.e. the carriage return inserts as new lines into my table. [Example of Data Inserted to Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ecFUe.png)

So I guess my question here is does anyone have any experience of using a Data Wrangling data flow to strip out carriage returns and if so can they give me a bit of guidance as to how they made it work? As far as I can see, the carriage returns are taken into account before it goes through the data wrangle - which kinda defeats the objective of using it!

Thanks

Nick

Comment: what's the expect result  in the table? It's not very clear from your question.

Comment: Hi Leon - apologies if I was unclear.

Comment: I have an excel file with one line in it, and about 10 columns. I want one line to be inserted into the corresponding ten fields in the table. However, in the file, one column has a cell with 5 carriage returns within it. Instead of seeing one line being inserted into the table, I see 5 - i.e. for each carriage return, it sees that as a new line and inserts it as a line in the table.

Comment: Further to that - the screenshot of the table shows the first column of the table, which should be a row ID. However, because of the line break, you can see the text from the cell which contains the text from the cell that contains the carriage returns (Which I have stripped out within the data wrangle) i.e. I can see the line break split into multiple rows

Comment: Hi @Churchy36, I create an excel with the same txt(cell with 5 carriage returns) with you, I load the data to SQL table with one row.  It works well on my side. So what's the source data, excel(.xlsx) or .csv? csv file usually open with excel.

Comment: Hi Leon - its a CSV file which I load into a blob from an SFTP site - I then pick it up from the blob and pass it into the data wrangle. I thought about trying to change the default file into a txt, but I'd then have to handle the comma embedded in the free text field... My next thing to try (not had time yet) is converting the field using the text.clean function, although the data wrangle seems to lack some of the functionality available in a full version of power query m... will let you know if that fixes it

Comment: Further update - doesn't look like that transformation is supported using data wrangling. Tells me to use a simpler expression.... I've encountered that a lot trying to transform my data, so this is definitely looks to be a limitation of the tool (in fairness it is only in preview). However if the inability to strip carriage returns is also bug (more likely something I am doing wrong though) makes the data wrangling pretty unusable for my use case... :(

Comment: @Chrchy36 Wrangling Data Flow is still in preview and the transformation is a little complex. The Azure Document is not very clear and doesn't provide enough details about how to use it. I suggest we could post the further update as the answer.

Comment: @LeonYue - yeah, I reluctantly think I have to agree. Was hoping that someone would tell me I was making a stupid mistake but that doesn't look the case. No doubt this will work fine in 6 months time....

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if this is a limitation of the tool currently - given it is only in preview, this will likely be resolved going forwards, however at this time it does not appear as if the functionality to strip carriage returns is working